# Function to center text

Tags: functions

I am remaking 2048 in java. I am trying to center the text of the number inside the box with a function, but I have some trouble translating the text since the $x$ and $y$ are on the bottom left of the text. I need to translate the $x,y$ as the center of the image and place that in the middle of the frame.

Mostly my trouble is with how many pixels in length and width the text is.

Given a font size, $f$, and a panel size, $p = 10$ (pixels) and an $x$, as well as the number of digits, $d$, how do I turn this into a function to translate the $x$?

**EDIT**:
[image: Here is the font]

Comment: Is there any way to convert the font size to the width of a digit?

Comment: I don't know you tell me!

Comment: It would depend a lot on the particular font, I would imagine. Try asking this question over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). They might have a way to center text in Java.

Comment: yeah? well I would if that was an option! the SO bot is a retard and requires refinement in the logic. I got one measely question closed and it kicked me out.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of the text depend on the specific font (typeface, size, weight, kerning and many more) and the specific string (different digits have a different width, unless you use a monospaced font). Therefore, such a formula does not exist.

However, many frameworks offer some way to **measure** text. Questions about that belong to StackOverflow.

Comment: Then what is a particular formula for monospaced font? I gave it a font of 64 and as more digits were added, the font would decrease according to the number of digits. And seperately, the font would determine the x and y coordinates of it, as well as the width of the total digits (monospaced, I only need something that determines width and height of a character, otherwise this would be simple!)